# R Applying labels of a vector to a database

Tags: database, r, function

given a database

```
> dat
     x   y      
[1,] "A" "alpha"
[2,] "B" "beta" 
[3,] "C" "gamma"
```

which defines the labels (specified in `d[,2]`) of the data in `d[,1]`, I would like to apply the labels to a vector

```
z
[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

arriving at a database

```
     z          
[1,] "A" "alpha"
[2,] "A" "alpha"
[3,] "A" "alpha"
[4,] "B" "beta" 
[5,] "B" "beta" 
[6,] "C" "gamma"
[7,] "C" "gamma"
[8,] "C" "gamma"
```

Unfortunately, my database is rather big: is there a quick way to do that, with built-in functions in R?

EDIT A modified version of the problem.

Given the database (of "rules" or "labels")

```
> dat
     x   y      
[1,] 1 "alpha"
[2,] 2 "beta" 
[3,] 3 "gamma"
```

I would like to apply the labels in `y` in a new (3rd) column to the database

```
> q
     z    
[1,] 1 0.1
[2,] 2 0.2
[3,] 3 0.3
[4,] 3 0.4
[5,] 2 0.5
[6,] 1 0.6
[7,] 1 0.7
[8,] 2 0.8
```

according to the values in `q[,1]`, i.e. `z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
dat <- as.matrix(data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:3],y=c("alpha","beta","gamma")))
z <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C")

rownames(dat) <- dat$x
dat[z,]

  x   y      
A "A" "alpha"
A "A" "alpha"
A "A" "alpha"
B "B" "beta" 
B "B" "beta" 
C "C" "gamma"
C "C" "gamma"
C "C" "gamma"
```

Comment: I edited my question to better approximate my original problem.